# search for a tuple value in a list of tuples

Tags: python

My datastruture is actually a dictionary that has a integer key and a value that is a list of tuples.
I want to find a particular index in that list.
For example:

```
 d = {}
 d[2] = [(1,-2),(2,4),(3,2)]
 d[1] = [(1,-2),(1,4)]
```

I want to find all tuples in a list with index 2 or -2 (they can be in either first or second member of the tuple). Then based on certain conditions I want to remove tuple elements from the list. For example, I want to remove (1,-2) from the  list d[2]. I did not find an efficient way to do this step because I also want to remove (1,-2) from the list d[1] whenever I remove it from d[2].

Comment: What's the index? What are those tuples?

Comment: For each dictionary index say 2, I have all the tuples that contain 2 or -2 in either the first or second tuple index.

Comment: See my approach, and use a sort on the tuple object, which will place them in order that way you can always delete from the lowest to he highest value.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> a = [(1,1), (2,2)]
>>> if (1,1) in a:
...     print 'Ok'
... 
Ok
>>>
```

---

To remove stuff:

```
>>> b = [(1,-1,(3,1),(5,2)]
>>> filter(lambda a: a != (1,-1), b)
```

Should give you:

> [(3,1), (5,2)]

**So..**

```
d = {}
d[2] = [(1,-2),(2,4),(3,2)]
d[1] = [(1,-2),(1,4)]

for k, v in d.items():
    d[k] = filter(lambda a: a != (1,-1), v)
```

This will remove (1, -1) from your dictionary all entirely.

Comment: The above way to remove (1,-1) is pretty inefficient. The entry (1,-2) will appear only in d[1] and d[2]. So I don't want to iterate the completely dictionary to remove (1,-2). Only d[1] and d[2]. Also initially, I want to search for instance of 1 or -1 in d[1] where 1 or -1 can be in either first or second index of the tuple. So I am not searching necessarily for (1,-1) together.

Comment: I just gave you a way to do it, how you implement it is up to you :)
You can choose not to iterate through the entire dictionary if you don't like to :) You didn't mention anything in your original question about just deleting 1 or -1, you stated `want to remove (1,-2)`, which, my function does and you can tweek it however you like and get the result you need. Note that you can't delete just 1 value from a 2 item tuple, that will cause issues unless you recreate the tuple, so there's no neat way to delete just one item in a list of tuples :)

Comment: I did not want to delete just one value. Just search for 1 or -1 in the list of tuples and then delete the tuple (say (1,-2)) that contains 1 or -1. Thanks for your help anyway.